# AngularJS, Cordova/IonicFramework: load index.hml from server

Tags: angularjs, cordova, web-applications, ionic-framework

## Background:

I'm loading my entire AngularJS Cordova/Ionic web-app from the server. This is amazing. I can change the app without going through Apple.

## Questions:

Q1) How can I use js-files.zip, loaded from server, in my index.html file?
Q2) How can I effectively load index.html startup logic from my server?

## Problems:

On some older devices, loading time is too high if I load all my .js files from my server, so I want to be able to configure that logic (in index.html) also from the server.

The only thing I'm not loading from the server is the content of index.html

So, how can I essentially load index.html from a server?

If i try to do that

1) Pulling, say, indexfromserver.html using ajax and doing html rewrite of index.html with document.write(res), then there are AngularJS problems:

E.g., module missing errors (*1 below), because the following isn't in index.html until after the ajax response rewrites index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

1.1) I can include the necessary modules in the initial local index.html, but then if I rewrite index.html, I'll get these errors/warnings about classList null in ionic (ask me for details), deviceready not fired, and angularjs loading more than once

2) I can redirect index.html to, say, indexfromserver.html, but then all my $http responses are rejected promises.

Regarding 2) I've been told I should be able to add a controller for indexfromserver.html or specify $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/indexfromserver');

This hasn't fixed the $http requests from being rejected.

I don't understand exactly how index.html is involved in making $http work correctly, as it doesn't have a controller and isn't the 'otherwise' route provided. I only see mention of index.html in config.xml so far.

## Request:

Can someone please post a snippet of a typical example how an AngularJS Cordova/Ionic app could effectively use index.html logic that's loaded from a server?

Otherwise, can someone show/explain if/how I can use js-files.zip from server, and uncompress and use in index.html?

## Details/Notes:

(*1) 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myapp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/nomod?p0=myapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pointed out that you can use JavaScript in certain situations to unzip an archive, but that is not very common. The web does not work like that, Ionic runs inside of a browser so you should use the same processes as you would to optimize a website.

You would build the app instead like any website. Take the following steps to create a more optimized app for loading quickly. If you aren't familiar with build tools, take a look at http://yeoman.io/, and this specific generator for Ionic https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic.

Here is a very basic list of some steps you can take, though the generator provides a few more options and other things could be added as well.

1. Concat and minimize your app's JavaScript into single file.
2. Concat and minimize your app's CSS into a single file.
3. Compress your angular templates with a tool like this https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates into a single JS file.
4. Deploy static assets to server.
5. Link to above assets in index.html.

Ultimately the goal is to optimize the assets so you don't have to load a lot of files, and each file is as compressed as possible.

Comment: This isn't correct. You certainly can load files from a zip, unpack them, and use them in your app. :-D stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Fair enough it appears you could technically do it but that is not something I would consider doing. There appears to be a lot of limitations, it adds overhead to handle unzipping, and doesn't even support compression.

Comment: Er, zip files do compress. And there isn't any reason you can't minify beforehand. Anyway, you'd have to make sure that the Cordova app caches the file, with your method. (in case internet isn't available and it isn't an internet-only app)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the zip file route, and you assume your users aren't always connected to the internet, probably the best way is to:

Check if the version is new via a server call, and if so, download the zip file, extract it (maybe via stuk.github.io/jszip/), and use a Cordova interface to write the new JS code to the phone's memory, and run the code by adding some script tags in your loader.